# Place validation message below a textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, validation

How can I have the validation message placed below the textbox and pushing the others controls down?
[This solution](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) is placing the text where I want it but if you have another textbox below it, the error message are displayed in it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the controls are placed. You can try by placing them in a StackPanel for example and you should see the controls pushed down when the message appair.